# Custom scrollbar not working in chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Project link:

```
http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/team/design/Camilo/
```

Custom scrollbar I used:

```
http://plugins.jquery.com/custom-scrollbar/
```

I have not modified any jquery related code, but called the custom scroller on two divs:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".demo").customScrollbar();
    $(".slider").customScrollbar();
});
```

I have made quite a few changes in the html of that plugin though. For instance, the basic html of the custom scrollbar plugin is:

```
<div id="idName">
    image
    image
    image
    image
    image...
</div>
```

I have introduced divs instead of image tags and then there is a show hide jquery on hover of those divs. You can observe this by going onto the project link and then clicking on this picture:

[image: Draw menu out]

Then click on the 'Furniture' menu item, which will bring image thumbnails. The horizontal scrollbar will display just below those thumbnails.

[image: Navigation]

This is how the thumbnails are displayed:

[image]

The horizontal scroll does not work on chrome but the vertical scroll is working.

Comment: And what is the problem? You don't need horizontal scroll bar? Read plugin's github: https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar
There is a parameter called hScroll, it indicates - show horizontal bar or not.

Comment: I need the horizontal scrollbar, it is not working on chrome at the moment. It is not draggable if you click it with mouse, where as it works on other browsers.

Comment: It is working in FF, IE, even Safari, but not in chrome.

Comment: Check the project link again if possible. You can see the vertical scroll is working but the horizontal scroll is not working. The hScroll is not needed, it works automatically according to the height and width of the div that it is being applied on.

Comment: What's your version of Chrome ? It's working fine for me (Version 30.0.1599.69 m)

Comment: Yes, I worked it out. Chrome was somehow not taking the width of class 'overview'. I calculated the total number of thumbs and divided by that total number of rows and assigned width to the 'overview' class.